# Clickhouse insert data across all replicas

Tags: sql, clickhouse

What I'm essentially looking for here is something along the lines of a [ddl](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/distributed-ddl) insert statement, from what I've found the functionality doesn't exist but I'm still looking to achieve the same end result.

Within my data model, I have a distributed table that I'm trying to insert into, the logic for this insert is a select statement from another distributed table that joins onto a small non-distributed merge tree table, the data within this table is static and should be the exact same across all replicas.

The problem here is that the data will only exist in one replica leading to potentially incorrect results when running the insert statement, is there a more elegant solution than just connecting to each replica individually to run the insert statements?

I don't want to enable [distributed_product_mode=allow](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#:%7E:text=distributed_product_mode%E2%80%8B,subquery%20for%20the%20distributed%20table.) as this can impact performance

**Table structure**

```
-- table that we select the data from for the insert
create table "select_table" on cluster default
(
    id UInt32,
    relation_id UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
order by id
;

create table "select_table_distributed" on cluster default
(
    id UInt32,
    relation_id UInt32
) ENGINE = Distributed(default, 'mydb', 'select_table', rand());


insert into "select_table_distributed" values (1, 1);

-- table that we need to join to 
create table "relation_table" on cluster default
(
    id UInt32,
    name String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
order by id
;

insert into "relation_table" (id, name) values (1, 'realtion_id_1');

-- table that the data is inserted into
create table "insert_table" on cluster default
(
    id UInt32,
    relation_id UInt32,
    relation_name String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
order by id
;

create table "insert_table_distributed" on cluster default
(
    id UInt32,
    relation_id UInt32,
    relation_name String
) ENGINE = Distributed(default, 'mydb', 'insert_table', rand());


insert into "insert_table_distributed"
select s.id, s.relation_id, r.name
from "select_table_distributed" s
join relation_table r on s.relation_id = r.id;
```

This will run fine if executed within the replica that has the relation_table data but will fail on the other replicas, how can i populate this table on all replicas without having to connect to each individually to run the insert, or is there perhaps a better approach to be taken here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that three approaches could have been taken here -

1. Connect to each replica and insert the required data for the relation_table, that way when the local query runs the correct results will be returned. This was not an elegant or viable solution for me.
2. Populate the relation table on one replica and use this as the only requestor server, then when executing the query use the global keyword to join onto the relation_table to pass the data to the other replicas. The global keyword here loads the relation_table data into a temporary table so that it is available for the other replicas. This is documented as a potential approach by [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/operators/in#:%7E:text=It%20also%20makes%20sense%20to%20specify%20a%20local%20table%20in%20the%20GLOBAL%20IN%20clause%2C%20in%20case%20this%20local%20table%20is%20only%20available%20on%20the%20requestor%20server%20and%20you%20want%20to%20use%20data%20from%20it%20on%20remote%20servers.) but should be used with **caution**. With this approach you first need to consider the size of your table and possibly even the deployment of your ClickHouse Cluster (covered in detail in the link above).

   ```
   --needs to be ran on the replica that contains the relation_table

   insert into "insert_table_distributed" 
   select s.id, s.relation_id, r.name
   from "select_table_distributed" s
   global join relation_table r on s.relation_id = r.id;
   ```

This also wasn't a viable solution for me as I didn't want to create a hard dependency on one given replica, with this approach you must ensure that the SQL executes on a specific replica, this is rather implicit by design and begs the question of maintainability further down the line.

3. Distribute the relation table and use the global keyword to pass on the full dataset to the other replicas. This was the solution I went with and it is similar to the second option, the only difference is that i don't have to worry about running the SQL on a specific replica.

   ```
   --create table
   create table "relation_table" on cluster default
   (
     id UInt32,
     name String
   )
   ENGINE = MergeTree
   order by id;

   --create distributed table
   create table "relation_table_dist" on cluster default
   (
     id UInt32,
     name String
   )
   ENGINE = Distributed(default, 'mydb', 'relation_table', rand());

   --insert into distributed table

   insert into "relation_table_dist" (id, name) values (1, 'realtion_id_1');

   --use global and select from the distributed table

   insert into "insert_table_distributed" 
   select s.id, s.relation_id, r.name
   from "select_table_distributed" s
   global join relation_table_dist r on s.relation_id = r.id;
   ```

This will select the full dataset from the distributed table into a temporary table and then pass that onto the other replicas for processing. It could be argued that it is redundant to distribute such a small table (<1k rows) but for me at least this was the best option available.

Comment: thanks for sharing your details with results here. Using the distributed table seems to make the most sense, so you can query any replica (even if that table resided on only a single replica). Seems like the simpler approach with using the GLOBAL JOIN, assuming your performance is also meeting expectations. Thanks for sharing!